# Hide Main Header for specific site on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to hide the Main Header from the SharePoint Online on particular site. I was wondering do we have script or css. As i do not wish to use with script editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done via out of box solution. And it is not recommended to custom the ribbon or suite bar.

If you really need to to do this, you may need to use things like modern script editor or add a SPFX Extension to add js file to home page.

Reference you can take:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fac8acca-40a3-42c4-a7e8-0666f9301704/how-to-remove-site-headersite-logo-site-title-from-sharepoint-online-modern-pages?forum=onlineservicessharepoint